# replacing values conditionally, adding comment

Tags: jq

the jq prints csv as in:

```
... | [.name, .userId, .groupId] | @csv'
```

what does print:

```
"nodea","0","6"
"nodeb","1","0"
```

how could I process it to get "n/a" instead of 0, and for >0 values appropriate note/comment, for example:

```
"nodea","n/a","group:6"
"nodeb","user:1","n/a"
```

Is it feasible in jq or only post processing, eg. in awk ?
thank you

Comment: post the input json

Answer (score 5):

**`jq`** solution:

Sample `input.json`:

```
[
    {
        "name": "nodea",
        "userId": 0,
        "groupId": 6
    },
    {
        "name": "nodeb",
        "userId": 1,
        "groupId": 0 
    }
]
```

---

```
jq -r 'def pr($k): if .[$k] > 0 then $k+":\(.[$k])" else "n/a" end;
      .[] | [ .name, pr("userId"), pr("groupId") ] | @csv' input.json
```

The output:

```
"nodea","n/a","groupId:6"
"nodeb","userId:1","n/a"
```